# PCIe Card with USB Device Mode support

Tags: usb, usb-device

I'm currently working on a BBB based project where we rely heavily on the BBB posing as USB Device (USB Device Mode via Linux/ConfigFS). The dev proccess is quite annoying though because we always have to tranfer a new firmware to the BBB to try things out (no shell/console on the device whatsoever due to security reasons). Everything else works/can be tested on the host - just not USB Device mode (which is a core functionality ... :-( ).

So I'm wondering if there is (PCIe) Hardware that provides USB Device Mode support on a regular machine. I did stumble accross http://www.hwtools.net/Adapter/PP3380-AB.html - however it's hard to get this hardware in Europe.

Any other pointers?

Comment: what is BBB...?

Comment: Sorry - working with acronyms all day. BBB is Beagle Bone Black (https://beagleboard.org/black)

Comment: how about getting another BBB and putting a shell/console on it?

Comment: it's your device, right? When I worked on embedded devices we put a root shell in our debug builds. Surely that security only matters when someone else buys it?

Comment: Using a second one (we have some of them in stock ...) or getting a root shell in the firmware is definetly possible - not easy but possible. This is only one part of the equation though. The BBB runs a custom built buildroot/busybox system. So each time we change something we rebuild the firmware. That's not possible /on/ the BBB (or would take ages). Also building on the host is way faster we still have to upload the new firmware (OTA thank god) ... Doing everything on the host (building and USB Device testing) would be way faster - hence the question.

Comment: can't you just update the files you changed?

Comment: We still need to recompile the project. We could try to monkeypatch a newly build binary into the firmware. Not even sure if this works as the firmware is signed.

Comment: maybe disable signing for your debug builds? It sounds like you have put a bunch of roadblocks in your own way

Comment: I fully agree on the roadblocks when developing /on/ the device ... as most of them are by intention. That's why I was checking for a host based solution where all those roadblocks wouldn't matter,

Comment: are they by intention for your customers or by intention for yourself? why would you put roadblocks in your own way?

Comment: The deployment will be in a high security area. So the requirements are from the customer side. We basically took the foundation from another project where all the hard stuff (e.g. signed firmware, disabled console (not even UART)), HSM with breach detection circuitry) was already in place. This isn't a real problem though as we are able to develop 95%+ on the host side. Just the UCD stuff isn't working. However we just ordered the card above (and some other samples) - once those arrive we can do 100% of the development on the host. So it's fast (on host) and still secure (on device).

Comment: the deployment **on the developer's desk** is not high security - there is no need to enable all the security features on that one! It sounds like you roadblocked yourself because you copied the roadblocks from another project and don't want to figure out how to turn them off - is that correct?

Comment: The security on the device is not something we're gonna change (and basically not allowed to). Those roadblocks are intentional on the device and non-existent on the host. Hence the question for host based UDC cards. Maybe to change the perspective - let's assume we have a board that we cannot develop on (very low powered CPU). We could how ever develop and test on the host if we'd be able to duplicate a hardware feature of the board - i.e. USB Device Mode support / UDC. That's why I was asking for a host based USB Device Mode/UDC hardware.